# How did the popup of this chrome extension open from bottom?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know about chrome extensions and I built one.

As far as I know, popup can only be opened from the button action (page action too) and will be closed once they lose focus (i.e. if users clicks somewhere on the webpage).

But how did this extension - [barc](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/barc/lkledilgabpellhganjgplgemmoadagh) manage to

**1)**  open from bottom

**2)**  refrain from closing even after losing focus

I looked at my `chrome://flags/#enable-panels` and found panels to be **disabled**. So, this ain't the cause.

I'll be happy if some one can point me to the underpinnings of this implementation or API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's injecting custom UI into pages via content scripts, not showing it in a panel.

You can test it by minimizing/moving the Chrome window.

Comment: Spot on @Xan! Thanks! Now, I figured out the mystery!

Comment: This may be another question -  I believe not every site allows to inject such custom UI into their pages. Am I right @Xan?

Comment: The site can do little to protect itself, considering that the extension has rights to execute arbitrary code on the DOM. However, it's not easy to inject custom UI consistently well.